# Disable a section of the mousepad?

Tags: touchpad, ultrabook

I purchased a hp envy 4 ultrabook. Its great but I'm infuriated at the touchpad. The click buttons and the touch pad are combined together but the click button area is touch sensitive. I usually rest my thumb on the right click but the mouse cursor goes completely crazy on this machine.

Is there any way to disable a section of the touchpad? Basically make the click button area have nothing to do with the pointer function.

I did see this post: [Disable touch pad for mouse button region on new HP pavillion models?](https://superuser.com/questions/229489/disable-touch-pad-for-mouse-button-region-on-new-hp-pavillion-models)

but the solution presented in that only limited the area from which the touchpad can begin. Since I rest my thumb on the click buttons, I would like to completely disable the click button area of the touchpad.

Comment: I don't think this is possible the way you describe it. You may just have to learn new behaviour, or use a mouse.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1386578
it seems doable on linux, i dont see why it cant be done on windows. maybe an autoit script?

Comment: Can you put a Post-IT note over it?